# Дождаться завершения работы второго потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть слушатель в главном потоке, он должен ждать ответа из другого потока.
Вот пример:

//ГЛАВНЫЙ ПОТОК

```
add("test", new listener() {
                @Override
                public void run(int index, Object obj) {
                    //ЭТО ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ ВТОРОЙ ПОТОК, через определенное время

                    //ЗАВЕРШИТЬ ОЖИДАНИЕ ГЛАВНОГО ПОТОКА, ТОЕСТЬ RUN ВЫПОЛНЕН

                }
            });
```

//ГЛАВНЫЙ ПОТОК должен ожидать завершения выполнения **run!**

Comment: Мне кажется не  в том месте вы хотите управлять ожиданием главного потока и прочими делами.... могу предложить использовать `interrupt` =)

Comment: Мне кажется очень странным, что главный поток должен кого-то ждать

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону использования `join`, `wait`

Comment: Лучше посмотреть в сторону `ExecutorService` и `Callable`, получить `Future` и вызвать `get()`. Если хочется более наколеночно, то можно через `CountdownLatch`. Но все равно странно, зачем выносить задачу в другой поток, если этот будет стоять до завершения.

Comment: Данная задача нужна мне например для того чтобы получить ответ из вне. Например порты, вы отправили комманду, и добавили фитчу, ожидать пока не прийдет данная комманда, что у нас есть 1. слушатель комманд, который выполняется тогда прийдет определенная комманда это хорошо, дальше вступает в роль код который описан выше, и если комманда(ответ) пришла, все продолжать работу.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров вы что-то неправильно спроектировали..... но если вам реально (судя по коду) необходимо в другом потоке ждать пока закончится главный поток, то у главного потока берете ссылку на него, например `Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread()` а в данном потоке ждете его выполнения `mainThread.join()`....... но выглядит у вас это всё чрезвычайно странно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как же все-таки правильно заставить поток уснуть и разбудить его из второго потока, сами исходники с официального oracle(но в одной функции)

```
public boolean setSleep(boolean newSleep){
        if(newSleep!=sleep){
            if(newSleep == true){ //ЗНАЧ ДОЛЖЕН СПАТЬ, вызывать в первом потоке!
                synchronized (obj) {
                    sleep = true;
                    while (sleep) {
                        try {
                            obj.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(newSleep == false){ //ВЫЗЫВАТЬ ИЗ ВНЕ
                synchronized (obj) {
                    sleep = false;
                    obj.notifyAll();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } ,SLEEP - BOOLEAN (по умолчанию false), obj (простой обьект нужен для синхронизации, Object obj = new Object()(можно и без него, указать synchronized в функции, но не тестил))
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод класса Thread:

```
public final void join();
```

Этот метод ожидает завершения того потока исполнения, для которого он был вызван­. Его имя отражает следующий принцип: вызывающий поток ожидает, когда  указанный поток присоединится к нему. Дополнительные формы метода jоin() позволяют  вызывать максимальный промежуток времени, в течение которого требуется ожидать завершения указанного потока исполнения.

Значит Вам в главном потоке, необходима получить ссылку потока_2 и заставить главный поток остановиться ожидая поток_2, методом:

```
ссылкаНаПоток_2.join();
```

в этот момент главный поток остановится и будет ожидать завершение потока:  ссылкаНаПоток_2, как только поток_2 отработает возобновит работу главный поток.

А вообще посмотрите лекции по роботе с потоками (там 4 лекции вроде) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FvbIGNUl8A - Иван Головач, очень не плохо тему доводит

Comment: Не советую пользоватся этой вещью, она считается устаревшей не за просто так. Вот пример: 1.поток уснул, 2.второй поток разбудил (ок!). 1.поток не успел уснуть, 2.поток успел разбудить (вывод 1.поток никогда не проснется)

Answer (score 0):

Я долго искал решения , мне нужно было подождать пока Appsflyer инициализируется. Я пытался использовать Thread но єто останавливало UI. В итоге я использовал AsyncTask

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(8000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                loadLink();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если нужно чтобы main thread ждал окончания нескольких потоков, можно использовать ещё такой вариант

```
while (true){
        if(!onethread.isAlive() && !twothread.isAlive() && !threethread.isAlive()) {
            do something in main thread
            break;
        }
    }
```