# Задержка через новый поток

Tags: java

Заметил, про если сделать задержку через новый поток, следующие действия ждать окончания потока не будут. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: {
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // пропустил трай кеч
    }
}; thead.start();
suck(); // это действие уже работает без задержки

Comment: Не делать задержку через новый поток)

Comment: Если хочешь дождаться окончания выполнения другого потока - одно из решений - метод join() https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490017/348511